# When I click on accept an invitation, I immediately get redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my invitation controller I have this where I want to customize saving a user when they accept an invitation:

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private

  def accept_resource
    resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    #......
```

When I click on accept an invitation, I immediately get redirected, it doesn't show me the "enter your new password" page:

```
Processing by InvitationsController#edit as 
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :resource_from_invitation_token rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I've tried to set this:

```
   config.allow_insecure_token_lookup = true
```

but it throwed an exception at startup.

```
devise 4.2
devise_invitable
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/wiki/How-To:-Allow-updating-additional-attributes-when-accepting-invitation

Comment: @flyte321, how will that help?